# Collating data from several .txt files into one .csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I have a bunch of text files each with some data in. I want to collate this data then write a new file containing all the data.

Expected output:
Given a list of text files in directory containing equal size output in want to collect this information into a single file.

For example. if text_file1.txt contains:

```
A B C
2 7 8
```

text_file2.txt contains:

```
A B C
3 6 9
```

and text_file3.txt contains:

```
A B C
3 6 8
```

the result.csv should look like:

```
A B C 
2 7 8
3 6 9
3 6 8
```

My code so far

```
import os
import glob
import re
import pandas

def collate_PE_results(self,directory,qualifier,outfile):
    os.chdir(directory) #cd to directory
    all_files=os.listdir(directory) #list all the files in this directory
    text_files=glob.glob('*.txt') # select text files only
    for i in range(1,len(text_files)): #iterate over all the text files
        p = re.compile(qualifier) #compile a string to search in the text file
        if p.search(text_files[i]): #search for the qualifier in the text file
            with open(text_files[0]) as f: # first match initiates the data frame
                df = pandas.read_csv(text_files[0],sep='\t')
        else:
            df.append(pandas.read_csv(text_files[i]),sep='\t') # the rest of the matches are appended onto the bottom of the growing dataframe
    df.to_csv(outfile,sep=',',header=df.keys())
```

This code runs and writes a .csv file but containing the wrong information - namely a single line of data on row 2 without a header. Could anybody suggest how to modify my code to get what I want? Thanks

---------------edit---------------------

To call this function I am creating an instance of the parent class

```
CT=Copasi_Tools.Cluster_Tools()
```

And then:

```
CT.collate_PE_results(directory,qualifier='Result',outfile) #Each file containing information has the word 'Result' in the file name
```

Comment: How are you calling this function???? Not trying to recreate the qualifier arg...

Comment: Instead compiling into a single dataframe, read each file's contents, splitlines(), into a list of lists such that [[lines_from_1],[lines_from_2],[lines_from_3]].  Then zip them together like zip(*list) and write that to a the new csv file.

Comment: @heinst - I have made an edit for the information you wanted.

Comment: @Saarrrr - How does  this strategy deal with the fact that each file has a header and I only need one header on the final file? (thanks for the responses by the way)

Comment: When you encounter your first file, read off the header line into a variable first. For all other files disregard the first line and read only the data into your nested list structure. Then write the header first, followed by your zip(*) product.